# Mismatched HandleDestroyed and HandleCreated

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# project I have a static class that keeps track of some text boxes. The text boxes need to be removed from the list to prevent memory leaks.

I have a static function to add a text box to the list:

```
public static void Add(TextBox tb)
{
    tb.HandleCreated += new EventHandler(TextBoxHandleCreated);
}

static void TextBoxHandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
     tb.HandleDestroyed += new EventHandler(OnHandleDestroyed);

     tbList.Add(tb);
}

static void OnHandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove it
    Remove(sender as Control);
}
```

I call the add function from the constructor of a `UserControl` on my `Form`. In the remove function I call `c.HandleDestroyed -= OnHandleDestroyed;` so I don't keep the control alive for that reason.

The `Remove` function is a simple loop to check and remove:

```
public static void Remove(Control c)
{
    foreach (Control cl in cList)
    {
        if (c.Equals(cl))
        {
            c.HandleDestroyed -= OnHandleDestroyed;
            cList.Remove(cl);
            //break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when my dialog is shown and then destroyed I expect the created and destroyed to match, but that is not the case. I get a few more create than I get destroy.

Why is that so?

Comment: What does the Remove-method look like?

Comment: There's no simple explanation for that, other than you forgetting to explicitly disposing the dialog form, a very common oversight.  Or your dialog form code using Controls.Remove or Controls.Clear without disposing the removed controls, a fatal oversight.  Your snippet is far too incomplete to have a shot at trying to reproduce the problem.  Use the debugger, you have the reference to the TextBox that didn't get destroyed so find out what happened to it.

Comment: Yes, I did found a suspicious Controls.Clear and it fixed most of the memory leaks. Thanks for the tip.